# Проблема с аргументами для функции _stprintf_s

Tags: c++, winapi

Вырезал из main кусок кода и вставил в функцию. Сразу же возникла ошибка в `_stprintf_s(szMsg, _T("%d"), data);`. Пишет, что `отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженной функции, соответствующие списку аргументов`. Что не так?

```
void sendData(int data, HANDLE hMutex, TCHAR szMsg[16]) {
    LPCTSTR pBuf = funcMap();
    _stprintf_s(szMsg, _T("%d"), data);
    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, nameForMutex);
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Так, небось, в *полном* сообщении об ошибке указаны и *какие именно* аргументы не того?

Comment: Обновил в вопросе.

Comment: Вот за неполный вопрос и вытягивание очевидных данных, нужных для ответа - в следующий раз проголосую за закрытие. Задолбали.

Comment: Ну, в Unicode-режиме ваша функция отображается на `int swprintf_s(wchar_t *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const wchar_t *format [, argument]...);`. Так что вы забыли размер буфера.

Comment: Хотя странно, должна была сработать перегрузка `template <size_t size> int swprintf_s(wchar_t (&buffer)[size], const wchar_t *format [, argument]... );`.

Comment: В main почему-то сработала, в функции - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`16` забыл передать. Это же "s"-функция.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, в чём дело. Всё не так тривиально.

Существуют [две перегрузки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) функции `_stprintf_s`:

```
int swprintf_s(
   wchar_t *buffer,
   size_t sizeOfBuffer,
   const wchar_t *format [,
   argument]...
);
```

для случая, когда размер буфера компилятору неизвестен, и шаблонная

```
template <size_t size>
int swprintf_s(
   wchar_t (&buffer)[size],
   const wchar_t *format [,
   argument]...
);
```

для того случая, когда он известен.

Если бы ваш код был таким:

```
TCHAR szMsg[16];
_stprintf_s(szMsg, _T("%d"), data);
```

— то это сработало бы, выбрав шаблонную перезагрузку.

Но вы передаёте `szMsg` как аргумент. Для параметров функций в C/C++ нету разницы между массивами и указателями, **массивы неявно и молча [приводятся к указателям](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)**. Поэтому с точки зрения языка `szMsg` — не что иное, как `TCHAR*`. Поэтому нужная перегрузка не вызывается.

Попробуйте переопределить свою функцию так, в стиле C++:

```
void sendData(int data, HANDLE hMutex, TCHAR (&szMsg)[16]) { ...
```

[[Проверка](http://ideone.com/j3ygnT)]

Или в стиле C, передайте в `swprintf_s` и размер, сработает нешаблонная перегрузка.

Comment: Теперь понятно :)